# How to customize a django form (adding multiple columns)

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Currently, I am building a form using the default django template like this:

```
class old_form(forms.Form):
    row_1 = forms.FloatField(label='Row 1')
    row_2_col_1 = forms.FloatField(label='Row 2_1')
    row_2_col_2 = forms.FloatField(label='Row 2_2')

html = str(old_form())
```

However, I would like to add multiple columns to my template, and still use django forms object to define parameters.

New temp. should something like (or it can loop through all the variables):

```
def getdjtemplate():
    dj_template ="""
    <table>
    <tr>{{ table.row_1 }}</tr>
    <tr>
      <td>{{ table.row_2_col_1 }}</td>
      <td>{{ table.row_2_col_2 }}</td>
    </tr>
    """
    return dj_template

djtemplate = getdjtemplate()
newtmpl = Template(djtemplate)
```

My question is how to 'combine' the new template and class `old_form()`?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the form HTML using its fields, [as shown in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template). You are doing this in an unusual way; normally you would have the template in a file instead of returning it from a function, but you can still do this:

```
from django.template import Context

def getdjtemplate():
    dj_template = """
    <table>
        {% for field in form %}
        <tr>{{ field }}</tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </table>
        """
    return dj_template

form = old_form()
djtemplate = getdjtemplate()
newtmpl = Template(djtemplate)
c = Context({'form': form})
newtmpl.render(c)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I think I will do something similar like `c = Context({'table': form})`